# Threads, synchronization, filling and removing int's from an array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, synchronization

I need to write a program, which has an integer array. Lets say the array's length is 3. To start with, it is empty. Now, the program has to use two threads, one writes integers into the empty array, the other one deletes them out of it. I will give you an example:

```
thread1 put in value 1 //array has value: 1
thread1 put in value 2 //array has two values: 1 and 2
thread2 deleted value 2 //array now has only one value: 1
thread1 put in value 3 //array has two values:  1 and 3
thread1 put in value 4 //array has three values: 1,3,4
thread1 wants to put value 5 into the array, but it has to wait, because the array is full
thread2 deleted value 4// array has 2 values: 1, 3 and so on........
```

My teacher said, it would be best and easiest to do all of this by implementing for cycles with a specified counter(for example each thread has to go through 10 cycles). Now i have written some code, but i just cant figure out how to implement the synchronized object(the integer array) so that both threads can use it. Heres the code:

```
public class Antras {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Program starts working");
    begin();
    System.out.println("Program ends work");
}

public static void begin() {
    synchronizationObject channel = new synchronizationObject();
    try {

        Thread putIn = new ReadThread(channel);
        putIn.start();

        Thread takeOut = new WriteThread(channel);
        takeOut.start();

        putIn.join();
        takeOut.join();

        System.out.println("main() ended work");
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        System.out.println("Error " + exc);
    }
}
}

class ReadThread extends Thread {

private synchronizationObject channel;

public ReadThread(synchronizationObject channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread " + this + "working");


    channel.working = false;
    System.out.println("Thread " + this + "ends work");
}
}



class WriteThread extends Thread {

private synchronizationObject channel;

public WriteThread(synchronizationObject channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread " + this + "working");


    System.out.println("Thread " + this + "end work");
}
}




class synchronizationObject {

public static int N = 3; 
int[] arrayOfInts = new int[N];

synchronized void takeOut() {

}

synchronized void putIn(int d) {

}
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have anything other then boilerplate in `WriteThread`/`ReadThread`/`synchronizationObject`; What have you tried so far?

Comment: you could start by reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Re, "an integer array ...[of] length 3. To start with, it is empty".  There is no such thing as an empty array.  Sounds like you are trying to describe a higher-level data structure (e.g., a `Set` or a `List`) that uses an array in its implementation.  I think you need to get a better understanding of how that higher-level object is supposed to behave, write some tests, create an implementation of your object that passes the tests,...  Do all that *before* you worry about thread safety or write any code that creates new threads.

Comment: probably BlockingQueue would fit more than array in your case

Comment: On second thought, Did your teacher tell you to implement your own Set or List or Queue class?  Java _has_ implementations of all of those classes that you can just use without writing any code.  Don't re-invent the wheel unless the purpose of the assignment is specifically to teach you how the wheel was invented.

Comment: @hahn, Not a queue, a stack!  In the OP's example output, whenever a value is "deleted", it's always equal to the last value that was added.

Comment: @jameslarge yeap, stack :)

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized int putIn(int d) {
     if(full == N){ 
         try {
            wait();
            System.out.println("Array full, thread waits");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
         buffer[idxdeti] = d;
         System.out.println("Value " + d + " added");
         idxdeti++;
         full++;
         if (idxdeti == N){
             idxdeti = 0;
         }
    }
    return d;   //returns the value
}
```

This is the WriteThread's run method:

```
 public void run() {
    System.out.println("WriteThread" + this + "started");
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        channel.putIn(i);   //puts in a value
    }
    System.out.println("WriteThread" + this + "ended");
}
```

Now I just don't know how to return a value to the takeOut method, so when it works, it removes the given value.